# Why can't I type some domain name strings in comments or messages on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I can't type some domain name strings in comments or messages on Facebook? It gives the following error:

> You can't post this because it has a blocked link
>
> The content you're trying to share includes a link that our security systems detected to be unsafe:
>
> gmailo.com
>
> 6l9.com
>
> Please remove this link to continue.
>   If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know.

`7.0.12.0` is another string that doesn't work.

Comment: It's probably identifying that you're trying to put an IP in...?

Comment: They don't want people to put in questionalbe links, and links using an IP address instead of DNS name are especially suspicious. to test that its an IP address pattern, put a space anywhere in the string.

Comment: It would be much more helpful to include the _actual_ error message. That said, I agree that Facebook is probably identifying it as an IP address and an attempt to link to a sketchy site. Have you tried enclosing it in quotes?

Comment: @AlE. Yes after enclosing it in quotes, it became a link with address 7.0.12.0

Comment: And have you tried contacting Facebook support about the issue, as the error message suggests?

Comment: @AlE. Yes I did but they haven't responded yet.

Comment: Why do you need to post those particular strings? It beggars belief that you don't already know why those strings are marked as "bad'.

Comment: @AlE. It's just for curiosity & knowledge. I came across one such post that offered $100000 for successfully commenting 7.0.12.0 there and no one could.

Comment: And that didn't strike you as odd? Sounds to me like a bad actor is trying to crowdsource getting around Facebook security.

Comment: I would suggest pointing Facebook support to that post so that they can investigate.

Answer (score 4):

The error message explains it clearly. It looks like you're trying to post links to sites that Facebook deems "unsafe", likely because it is overtly or secretly set up to use exploits to compromise the system of whoever visits. (Google does much the same thing in their search results and with the Chrome browser.)

Facebook tries to be helpful by converting text that looks like a web domain into a link, because most people aren't savvy enough to do it themselves. But those particular strings happen to be for bad actors. Unless you're trying to tell people not to go to those sites, I can't think of a single reason you need to be able to post them.